# Does the Steam Deck have an accelerometer? Is it accessible as Linux a kernel device?

Tags: linux, kernel, steam, steamos

I've just finished porting my app (that I've been developing for 15 years) to Linux. iOS is moving sideways and for my app it has been deprecated. The Steam Deck is one of my new target devices. On Asus/Lenovo/HP touchscreen computers I can find one (or two) accelerometer device(s) at /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device# or /dev/iio:device#. The Steam Deck is also supposed to have an accelerometer chip but I can not find it, or any real evidence that it exists. I did ask Valve but I only got a reply and not an answer to my question. Does anyone know anything about the existence of an accelerometer chip in the Steam Deck?

p.s. I searched /dev looking for accelerometer raw data for 2 days. I also tried installing Pop OS Linux on the Deck but the results were the same

Comment: Valve seems to [recommend](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/steamdeck/recommendations) using their [Steam Input API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/isteaminput#InputMotionData_t).

Comment: accelerometers are under `/drivers/iio/accel` in the kernel source.

Comment: raw data (but not in the Steam Deck) is at /dev/iio:device# or /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device#, I corrected my question